# strongly convex normed space

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, convex-optimization, finsler-geometry

A space is said to be convex if the unit ball is a convex set.

This definition gives the intuition about the convex normed space. Now I am wondering what would be the similar definition for a **strongly convex space**?

P.S. This is more related to Randers-Finsler spaces.

Comment: Do you mean strictly convex? The image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space) suggests that a normed space is strictly convex if and only if the unit ball is a convex set which contains no line segments of its boundary.

Comment: @mechanodroid No! Actually I mean strongly convex which is different with strictly convex!

Comment: The unit ball is _always_ convex. It is not, however, always strictly convex. See the Wikipedia page @mechanodroid offered. As for whether there is an interpretation for "strongly" convex, +1 to FTP's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the term "strongly convex" is commonly used for normed spaces. But if it was, then by analogy with strongly convex functions, which satisfy 
$$
f\left(\frac{x+y}2\right) \le \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} - c\|x-y\|^2
$$
they would be "spaces with quadratic modulus of convexity".

The [modulus of convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_and_characteristic_of_convexity) is defined as the function
$${\displaystyle \delta (\varepsilon )=\inf \left\{1-\left\|{\frac {x+y}{2}}\right\|\,:\,\|x\|=\| y\| = 1,\ \|x-y\|\geq \varepsilon \right\},}$$
The space is uniformly convex if $\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ for every $\varepsilon \in (0, 2]$. This is already stronger than "strictly convex".
A stronger property yet is having *quadratic modulus of convexity*, which means there exists $c>0$ such that
$$
\delta(\varepsilon) \ge c\varepsilon^2, \quad \forall \ \varepsilon \in (0, 2]
$$ 
This is the strongest kind of convexity that makes sense for a normed space. Examples of such spaces are $L^p$ and $\ell^p$ with $1<p\le 2$.

Comment: I know "strongly convex" from definition of Randers norm. The Randers norm is strongly convex and I think it is something common in Geometry. Maybe changing the tags of my question makes it more clear. You may search "the Randers norm is strongly convex" to see.